# How to Measure Total Duration of Video Files in a Directory?

Tags: linux, command-line, video

Let's say I have a directory with 5 video files in it. How can I measure the total duration of all video files in this directory from terminal. Also, I want to be able to do this recursively to any subdirectories it may has. I don't want to use VLC or any other GUI tools, since I've many directories to perform this action on, and it take a lot of time for me to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? What research have you done? :)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170961/get-total-duration-of-video-files-in-a-directory

Comment: @djsmiley2k Thanks for the help. The [first answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170973) on that thread solves my problem for a single directory. However, most of my directories have subdirectories with video files. Can you please explain, how to do it recursively for subdirectories? I used this command: `exiftool -S -n ./*.mp4 | awk '/^Duration/ {print $2}' | paste -sd+ -| bc`

Comment: -1. Feedback: your question shows no research effort and this comment continues with the attitude: "Can you please explain, how to do it recursively for subdirectories?" Learn how the linked answer works (`man find` is your friend): what `-maxdepth` is, what `-exec` is. Experiment. [Edit] the question and tell us what exactly you have tried, where you are stuck. Not knowing is not a shame, nor is failing; but not trying is.

Comment: Are you saying I have to study a whole manual for a simple question? I mean, I've already got what I need (the command). I just need an automated way to apply it recursively, instead of going to each directory, writing it, and tracking the outputs manually.

Comment: Technically you don't have to. You can do no research and still get some answers sometimes and some downvotes often. I'm giving you a feedback on where these downvotes come from, plus an advice on what to do to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, the command from anotehr thread works for a  single directory, but not multiple subdirectories.

This command will use find to get files from all subdirectories (ending in .mp4)

`find ./ -name *.mp4 -exec exiftool -S -n {} \;`